# Как управлять шаблонов вывода в Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

Тогда, когда есть массив данных с разным ключом, по его типу нужно сформировать шаблон HTML.

Например:

```
$arr = ('1' => array('name' => 'Pop'), '2' => array('seed' => 30))
```

Тогда в шаблоне HTML используя `ng-repeat`:

```
if(key == '1'){
   {{item.name}}
}

if(key == '2'){
  {{itemseed}}
}
```

Comment: Не понял, какой у тебя вопрос?

Comment: Имею ввиду то, что в результирующем массива от аякса - есть итемы разного рода с разной информацией. Для каждого нужно отобразить свой шаблон HTML на странице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам может помочь директива [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

Внутри `ngRepeat`, напишите что-то типа

```
<div ng-switch="key">
  <div ng-switch-when="1">Шаблон для ключа с 1</div>
  <div ng-switch-when="2">Шаблон для ключа с 2</div>
</div>
```